# Need to fetch result of only one column from the MySQL status variables

Tags: mysql, query

I wanted to fetch only the value from status variables. Suppose the query is

```
show status where Variable_name='Aborted_clients'
```

It returns

```
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| Aborted_clients | 4     |
+-----------------+-------+
```

From here I need to fetch only the value of column "Value".
Is there any way.
When I am trying to this query as sub query, it is throwing error.

I am using MySQL version 5.0.24.
And OS is windows

Comment: The best answer I saw to this is from SO - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4326773/3812704 - `mysql -sse "select VARIABLE_VALUE 
from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS 
where VARIABLE_NAME = 'Aborted_clients';"`

Answer (score 2):

Go to information_schema database and do a select from the global_status table instead:

```
mysql> use information_schema;
Database changed
mysql> select * from global_status where variable_name='aborted_clients';
+-----------------+----------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME   | VARIABLE_VALUE |
+-----------------+----------------+
| ABORTED_CLIENTS | 22             |
+-----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select variable_value from global_status where variable_name='aborted_clients';
+----------------+
| variable_value |
+----------------+
| 22             |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: I am using MySQL version 5.0.24, so the table global_status is not present in information_schema

Answer (score 1):

```
$ mysql -u root -p --skip-column-name -e \
    "show status where variable_name='Aborted_clients';" | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

If you want to do it in a shell script, put a `~/.my.cnf` file in $HOME with belows content:

```
[mysql]
user     = root
password = pa$$w0rd
host     = localhost
```

---

If you are running MySQL on Windows, take a look at [gawk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm):

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin>mysql.exe \
    --skip-column-name -u root -p -e \
    "show status where variable_name='aborted_clients';" | \
        "C:\Program Files(x86)\GnuWin32\bin\awk.exe" "{ print $2 }"
```

Comment: I am working on windows based, also I need a MySQL query to get the output which will be used in our application.

Comment: You can use gawk: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm

Comment: The option is `--skip-column-names` not `--skip-column-name` (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_skip-column-names).

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can use the following:

```
C:\> mysql -u... -p... -A -N -e"show global status like 'Aborted_clients'" > abc.txt
```

This will echo two tokens

- Aborted_clients
- the number

I am not a Windows expert, but I do know something you will have to emulate from Linux.

The [**awk command**](http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-awk.html) is what you would need.

```
C:\> mysql -u... -p... -A -N -e"show global status like 'Aborted_clients'" | awk '{print $2}'
```

The problem is that awk does not exist in Windows batch language or in PowerShell. However, [here is a nice blogpost on how to emulate it in Windows PowerShell](http://windows-powershell-scripts.blogspot.com/2009/06/awk-equivalent-in-windows-powershell.html).

I hope it helps.